# Как сделать сайт видимым для всех?

Tags: openserver

На сайт можно зайти только со своего компьютера. Как сделать, чтобы можно было хотя бы по локальной сети заходить на него? Сайт установлен на Open-Server

Comment: Подкорректировал вопрос

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Для начала убедитесь, что в Вашей сети локальный IP адрес для компьютера, где располагается Ваш сайт, статический. По умолчанию IP адреса на машины раздаются динамически и изменяются при перезагрузке в зависимости от того, кто первее загрузился. Каждая ось имеет свои особенности, а ось Вы не указали.
2. В большинстве случаев на компьютере с Вашим сайтом будет установлен антивирус с файерволом или включен файервол/межсетевой экран/брандмауэр. Он будет блокировать подключения от других компьютеров к Вашему (где лежит сайт). Необходимо снять блокировку и разрешить доступ других машин на Ваш IP адрес. Вариантов антивирусов с файерволами очень много. Для каждого приводить инструкцию бессмысленно. Смотрите в их документацию.
3. Доступ к Вашему сайту будет осуществляться либо по IP адресу, либо, можно создать .htaccess файл (и положить его в корень сайта), где прописать сопоставление IP адреса с каким-либо именем. Но это уже после того, как убедитесь, что он доступен по IP адресу. Также необходимо знать, где лежит Ваш сайт (в каких папках и как). Этого в вопросе нет.